# 1 Microservices - 1 Database - DDD Suggestion please

Tags: domain-driven-design, microservices

I am looking for a suggestion from design perspective.

I know 1 microservice - 1 database, is one of the fundamental principle of Microservice.

But i have peculiar issue:

1) It's an IoT project where data sends huge volume of data, most of the time creates/updates/status of a Device.

2) User tracks the status of the Device on UI every now and then.

Design I followed:

1) Designed a service(DeviceSubscribeService) a subscription model from KAFKA(device sends events to KAFKA). It keeps reading the data from KAFKA and inserts to database (DEVICE). This service is used only for Inserts/Updates.

2) Designed one more service (DeviceAPIService) a RESTFul service, which fetches data from the same database (DEVICE). This service is used only for Querying database.

Is this design/approach correct ? But as per Microservice principles 1 service 1 DB is broken.
is there any better way to do it ?

Is it a good approach from DDD perspective. I am using same Domain Model in both the the services to Insert and to Query DB.

Maintaining 2 databases for these 2 services and replicating data to keep them in sync, to keep things simple i would like to avoid such complex process. Trust me, it's working perfectly fine for me as of now.

But i am not too convinced from design perspective. Am i breaking any principle.

Please suggest.

Comment: Why aren't these two part of the same microservice? Would you consider them different Bounded Contexts? If so, why? My initial reaction is to consolidate them and then break them out if your future requirements demand it.

Comment: If i keep those two parts in same microservice, that would impact performance of read. As the service would be always busy in receiving data from KAFKA and inserting into DB. There could be hundreds of messages pumping in a minute. It becomes write intensive. In between i don't want to go to the same service and ask the device details. I thought it would be better to split them away and keep read and write in separate services.

Answer (score 0):

Using a shared database for applications that read/write rate is high, can introduce negative impact to your application performance.

CQRS architectural style, is a good choice to this satiation.
But performance issues, almost always has multiple causes.

If your current overall performance is satisfactory, is not necessary to use two separate database.